# Wordpress - MooTools sub-menu not working correctly

Tags: wordpress, mootools, wordpress-theming

I have installed the Akiraka theme from RocketTheme and am trying to get my sub-menu's working.  Currently when I hover over the main menu item a white box displays where the sub-menu items should be.

The site is:  http://testing.bfcmv.org/

I have compared everything to their site and can't see any difference between my configuration and their configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use the most recent version of WordPress 3.2.x and found that I should have been using a 2.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser/OS are you using?  It looks to be working OK for me.

Tested on Linux Firefox/Chrome